# Why do we need to halve superficial damage?

Tags: damage, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Why was this rule created with dividing superficial damage in half? I mean it's very confusing, why couldn't the number of hit points be multiplied by 2? Do I have to ask players to remember to divide by 2 every time? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack! You may find the [tour] helpful! Are you asking directly about designer intent? Or perhaps more details on the differences between the two? This format works better when we're presented with a solvable problem. What difficulty are you having with superficial damage, if any?

Comment: You're question may end up closed, but that just means we're waiting for clarification and it can be reopened after its edited. So if that happens, please don't be discouraged. Happy Stacking!

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, as it's a legit head scratch for newcomers to Vampire. That rule is a leftover from previous versions where bashing damage was halved. There were then 3 tiers of damage: bashing, lethal, aggravated instead of just superficial and aggravated in V5. The game designers wanted to (show they worked hard to) simplify it, so removed a tier. But they still wanted to distinguish between normal damage, supernatural claw damage and fire damage. So still 3 tiers, duh. They chose to reuse the old “halving” rule to re-create that third tier without identifying it as a tier…

Comment: … not the best move in my opinion since divisions (with the inevitable rounding up/down) are infamously dis-immersive and confusing for players, and these are now much more frequent in V5 than in V20 where bashing damage was pretty rare. Also, despite what the accepted answer says, the decision to remove soak rolls - albeit also made with simplification in mind - is tangent to all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It replaces the soak roll.

Anything you used to be able to soak with Stamina now gets halved. Instead of another die roll, it's a little bit of math.